# Qt Android: where is my file if I write to "./myfile.txt"?

Tags: android, c++, qt, path

I am porting my Qt desktop app to Android. 
In the desktop version, I will get a `myfile.txt` in the same folder of the executable file when I write to `./myfile.txt`. 
After I ported it to Android, the app runs smoothly but I cannot find the file anywhere as I'm new to Android...

So where is the file? Is there any concept like `pwd` for an Android app?

I'm using `QFile` and `QTextStream` to generate and write the file.

```
QFile file;
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream stream(&file);
stream << "something";
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be in "application storage".

/data/data/com.example.yourAppPackageName/

or in sd-card application storage

/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.yourAppPackageName/

Comment: I found the file in `/data/data/com.example.myapp/files/` in my case.